# How to var_dump from CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I am attempting to do a var_dump from a controller to my log file and I’m left with an empty line.

Here’s the code within my controller:

```
$checked = 'test error';
log_message('error', var_dump($checked));
```

In my log file, I get:

> ERROR - 2014-06-23 12:30:34->

I am able to get the result of:

```
$checked = 'test error';
log_message('error', $checked);
```

So, it must be an issue with var_dump()?

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: what happens when you just do a var_dump($checked) on its own? Or in the view?

Comment: In php var_dump is void.

Comment: Works fine from the view. I get the correct output.

Comment: @MohanShanmugam I'm not sure I understand the full meaning of void. If I'm able to get the result in the view, I would expected the same in the log. BTW, var_export gives me no result as well.

Comment: I assume we need to pass a message string in log_message. So assign a output of var_dump in one variable and pass that variable to log_message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on PHP `var_dump()` documentation, `var_dump()`[LINK](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.var-dump.php) doesn't return, it only outputs.

Therefore you can use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) PHP function like the following:

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   var_dump($data);
   $result = ob_get_contents(); //or ob_get_clean()
   //ob_end_clean() 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

var_export($variable, true) will do what you want. Basically you need to return a string, not echo directly. Which is what var_dump does. I suppose you could use output buffering but thats a bit... too much.

Comment: I need to see the variable type, otherwise this would have worked. Thanks